# How to make a 'simple query' of a large array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this line of code:

```
// echo the name of one forum (without additional DB query)
echo ($mybb->cache->cache['forums'][19][name]);
```

This gives the name of one forum. I need to list all forums by "querying" the array. Obviously, a simple db query could do this, but the info is already available.

How to iterate all the 'forums' and echo their name?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+iterate+multidimensional+array+php

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=iterate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=5J&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=query+an+array+php&oq=query+an+array+php&aq=f&aqi=g-K1&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.2183.3622.2.3973.5.5.0.0.0.0.178.812.0j5.5.0.eqn%2Crate_low%3D0-015%2Crate_high%3D0-015%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Ccconf%3D0-6.1.0.0.OU321EmzZq4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=64ca53ca10d28ad0&biw=1280&bih=884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($mybb->cache->cache['forums'] AS $forum_id => $forum_data) {
    echo '<li>'.$forum_data['name'].'</li>';
}
```